# angularFireCollection callback Firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

What if I don't want to directly assign my collection like this:

```js
$scope.items = angularFireCollection(ref);
```

Because I need to access the object in a callback once it's received:

```js
angularFireCollection(ref, function(items) {
  angular.forEach(items, function(item){
    angular.forEach(item.tags, function(tag){
      $scope.allTags.push(tag);
    });    
  });
  $scope.items = items;
});
```

Does a callback method exist for the `angularFireCollection` service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is, from the documentation on [explicit binding](https://angularfire.com/documentation.html#explicit):

> `angularFireCollection` takes an optional second argument - a callback that will be invoked when the initial data has been loaded from the server. The callback will be provided with a [Firebase snapshot](https://www.firebase.com/docs/javascript/datasnapshot/) as the only argument.

So you could call another function in the callback that will iterate over `$scope.items` directly to load the `$scope.allTags` array, or do something like you are now but use the snapshot instead (e.g. use the [`forEach()`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/javascript/datasnapshot/foreach.html) function).

Answer (score 0):

Use `.val()` as an extension of the object returned by the callback to access it's value.

```js
$scope.items = angularFireCollection(ref, function(i){
    console.log(i.val());
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3WcWu/1/)